# C# Async Function To Replace Mongo Document Does Not Work

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am currently running into an issue where I am unable to replace a Mongo document thats supposed to be updated with the following function:

```
public async void updateSelectedDocument(BsonDocument document)
        {
            var collection = mongoClient.GetDatabase("db").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
            var id = document.GetElement("_id").ToString().Remove(0, 4);
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
            var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, document, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
        }
```

There is no error to go off of and none of the variables are null. My connection to the mongo instance and collection works because I can perform a find and an insert. Please Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing an exception because the async method returns void? Have you tried either changing it to `async Task` or wrapping the method body in a try catch block and breaking in the catch body?

Comment: see `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx`, exceptions thrown in `async void` methods can't be caught within enveloping try catch blocks, so you may be missing an exception. Otherwise I don't see any obvious problems with the code you posted.

Comment: For the most part, that worked. The only thing thats off is that the application is inserting the updates as a new document instead of replacing the old document. Any ideas?

Comment: You've confirmed that the id of the document passed to `ReplaceOneAsync` matches the id of the document in the database? Also, for some reason I want to say that `Filter.Eq("_id", id)` should read `Filter.Eq("id", id)`, but I'm not sure, give that a shot.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but `document.GetElement("_id").ToString().Remove(0, 4);` could be returning a string with whitespace which does not quite match the id field in the db.